# Passing variables to a theme from a custom module

Tags: theming

I have a custom module which initiates the theme hook - passing the $node object as an argument:

```
theme('my_widget', array($node));
```

```
function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_widget' => array(
      'template' => 'my_widget',
      'variables' => array('node' => array($node)),
    ),
  );
}
```

However, in the 'my-widget' template file, I need to pick up the $node variable. But doing a dpm() on $node returns Null.. - think I may be setting the variable incorrectly, but not sure what's going on. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct code is the following one.

- Theme call

  ```
  theme('my_widget', array('node' => $node));
  ```
- Theme declaration

  ```
  function my_module_theme() {
    return array(
      'my_widget' => array(
        'template' => 'my_widget',
        // This array contains the default values.
        // You should not use a PHP variable.
        'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: how to print this variable in tpl file (ie) in my_widget.tpl.php

Comment: @user3386779 print it like this `<?php print $node; ?>`